# Cannot open .sql files in Visual Studio: Object reference not set

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a database project (dbproj) which loads without any problems. But when I double click one of the .sql files it contains I get the popup "Object Reference Not Set to an instance of an object". I tried reinstalling SQL Data Tools for VS2010. I do not have the option to convert to the newer sqlproj files.

What could be the problem?